ROS2 Humble Nodes and Topics Don't Show Up
When running nodes in ROS 2, the nodes and the topics that they publish or subscribe to do not appear when ros2 node list and ros2 topic list are run. While no errors appear, they do not publish or subscribe to topics as expected.
For example, when I run the talker demo with ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker I can see print statements that it is publishing methods but I cannot see the node when I run ros2 node list from another terminal on the same computer and when I run ros2 topic list I can only see the /paremeter_events and /rosout topics. This happens when I run the turtlesim demo code as well.
I have tried stopping and starting the ROS 2 daemon but it did not make a difference. Furthermore, I even uninstalled and reinstalled ROS 2 but with no success. Interestingly, I had ROS 2 working properly before but then this problem appeared. Any suggestions to troubleshoot what might be going wrong?
The computer is running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, the latest release of ROS 2 Humble, and the default DDS middleware rmw_fastrtps_cpp. Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.
My problem seems to be similar to this post, but in my case the nodes are on the same computer as the terminal that is running ros2 node list and it is not clear that the provided solution solved the OP's issue.

Did you export your ROS_DOMAIN_ID?

@yigitboracagiran Thanks for your response, I believe so. I've added export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=11 to my .bashrc file and when I run echo $ROS_DOMAIN_ID in each of the terminals I get 11. I've also tried removing the export from by .bashrc and then get 0 when I echo the variable as expected. So it seems that they are using the same domain ID

Maybe related to DDS?

That's what I'm wondering. Do you know how I could test the DDS and/or switch over to Cyclone DDS to see if that fixes it?

You need to export it in ~/.bashrc file. export rmw implementation=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp. But don't forget to check if cyclone is installed.

I installed cyclone and set it as the DDS and it works! I'm guessing that there must be something wrong with my Fast DDS configuration somehow, but I'm not sure why reinstalling ROS didn't fix it as that should've reinstalled Fast DDS too. I believe I should be able to use Cyclone for now, thanks for your help!

You're welcome, happy to help.

The problem in the end was that I was using the discovery server networking option but did not have a discovery server running! If that doesn't solve your problem becuase you're already running a discovery server, make sure you are running your ROS 2 CLI commands as a Super Client (see below) as that can cause a similar problem.
I am using a Turtlebot 4 robot which was automatically starting the discovery server, but recently I had been trying run programs just on my local machine without turning on the Turtlebot. Without a discovery server nodes couldn't find each other or other topics.
The reason why reinstalling ROS didn't help is that the discovery server settings were applied  in my .bashrc file so I was automatically using it. Switching to CycloneDDS temporarily solved my problem on my local machine since nodes could now see each other through simple discovery (apparently resetting your RMW_IMPLEMENTATION removes any discovery server setup and uses simple discovery again).
If you were running the discovery server already but you still can't see nodes when running ros2 node list then it's probably due to the traffic network reduction that the Discovery Server v2 does. In that case you need to instantiate a ROS 2 Daemon using the Super Client configuration to see all of the network traffic and nodes (see here for more information):
export FASTDDS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=super_client_configuration_file.xml
ros2 daemon stop
ros2 daemon start
ros2 node list
ros2 topic list

Thanks to @yigitboracagiran for helping me to narrow down the problem!
